# Mass production for Ubuntu systems

Tags: fstab, clone, clonezilla, uuid

I'm working on a project that is based upon an industrial PC. It runs Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
Right now I finished the development and I have a PC with a ready-to-use environment:

- customized Ubuntu installation (removed unused packages, added other ones, udev rules, configurations for services, etc...)
- end user applications, resources, web server, ...

The boss is asking: "well, let's be ready to prepare 50 PCs like this one".
The PCs are identical of course.

My first thought is to clone the SSDs (one for `/` and home, another for media contents) with Clonezilla.

I read several tutorial on the Internet that explains how to save the images of the HDDs and how to restore them.

But I wonder about the fstab for example:

```
# <file system>                           <mount point>   <type>  <options>                    <dump>  <pass>
UUID=a2063e54-9179-4855-8d24-173faf9e54b0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro            0       1
UUID=82AB-EC9F                            /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077                   0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw                           0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f6de388b-fe5a-4a23-a3c1-d87eb32f745a /mnt/resources auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0       0
```

After write back the original image to a new PC, would the o.s. even run? Or will it fail because the wrong UUIDs?

What's the correct approach to prepare a "mass" production cloning an existing system?

I'm not afraid about hostname or network configuration because I wrote a simple script that runs once at first boot. The problem is reach the first boot!

Comment: Without having expertise knowledge about it, I believe you should look into an automation tool (like Ansible) for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in a consistent fashion, [Canonical’s Metal-as-a-Service (MAAS)](https://maas.io/) is worth a look. It makes life a whole heck of a lot simpler.

Be sure to also examine [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/), which will drastically simplify updates, custom repositories, software deployments, and health monitoring.

These two tools have saved me (and my employer/clients) several thousands of hours per year.